# How to get string array values in HttpHandler ProcessRequest.?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, httphandler

I am passing strng array values to handler. But i am unable to read that values in HttpHandler ProcessRequest. How can i get that values.?

ClientSide Code:

```
var advSearchTypes=["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]; $.ajax({ url: 'SearchHandler.ashx', type: 'post', data: ({"SearchKey": searchKey,"AdvSearchTypes": advSearchTypes}),
    success: function (response) { }, error:function(){ } });
```

Handler Code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) { 
    string aSearchKey = context.Request.Form["SearchKey"].ToString();

    string[] aSearchTypes = context.Request.QueryString["AdvSearchTypes"].Split(','); }
```

`context.Request.QueryString["AdvSearchTypes"]` is showing null.

How can i get my string array values.?

Comment: Request.Form for POST, QueryString is for GET

Comment: You would end up with something like `AdvSearchTypes[]=abc&AdvSearchTypes[]=def...` passed using GET and something similar for POST, pass `advSearchTypes.join(",")`

Answer (score 1):

you can change here

from `type=post` to `get`

```
var advSearchTypes=["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]; $.ajax({ url: 'SearchHandler.ashx', type: 'get', data: ({"SearchKey": searchKey,"AdvSearchTypes": advSearchTypes}),
    success: function (response) { }, error:function(){ } });
```

Or in handler code

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) { 
    string aSearchKey = context.Request.Form["SearchKey"].ToString();

    string[] aSearchTypes = context.Request.Form["AdvSearchTypes"].Split(','); }
```